# Retain on boolean type

Tags: objective-c

When  I do

```
[itsBool autorelease];
itsBool = [aBool retain];
```

I have the warning : Receiver BOOL is not id or interface pointer.
Can you explain me why please?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like you should get a warning on `autorelease` as well. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOOL is a value type, like C structs. You cannot make references to BOOL values. BOOL is also not an Objective-C object type so you cannot retain/release values of type BOOL or send them messages. People often refer to non-object types as primitive types.

BOOLs are passed by value--they are copied whenever they are assigned to a variable:

```
BOOL x = YES ; // x contains the value YES (not a reference to YES)
BOOL y = x ;   // the value of x is copied to y
BOOL x = NO ;  // we assign new contents to x; the value of y is still YES
```

So, no need to retain/release them anyway.

For comparison, when dealing with Objective-C object references:

```
NSMutableString * x = [ NSMutableString string ] ; // x is a reference to a newly-created NSMutableString object
NSMutableString * y = x ; // y contains a copy of x, a reference to the mutable string we created previously. y and x refer to the same string object
[ x appendString:@"appended" ] ; // we alter the mutable string referred to by x

// y and x both point to the same mutable string, which now contains "appended".
NSLog(@"%@\n", x ) ; // prints "appended"
NSLog(@"%@\n", y ) ; // also prints "appended"
```

Comment: Ok thank you. So my getter is just like :
itsBool = aBool; ?

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL` is a primitive type. You can't send messages at it. You can't release or retain it. This is only possible with "real" Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do retain/release to pointer objects(suffix with *). BOOL is a primitive data type just like int/double/float/long.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I can't use a BOOL as a member variable type ?

Comment: You can use a BOOL as a variable but it will have just a value. No memory is allocated to it. It cannot be treated as an object.